# DependencyProperty not triggered

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I defined property in my usercontrol like this:

```
 public bool IsSelected 
 {
     get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
     set
     {
         SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
         StackPanelDetails.Visibility = value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
     }
 }

 public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", typeof (bool), typeof (ucMyControl));
```

But when I set its property in xaml, it want trigger it (set is not called).

```
 <DataTemplate><local:ucTopicItem IsSelected="False" /></DataTemplate>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does the class ucMyControl contain a collection of ucTopicItem objects? Or are they the same thing? You are registering the DP on ucMyControl, but setting it on a ucTopicItem. You also might want to try RegisterAttached instead of Register.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The setter of your dependency property will not be called when the property is set in XAML. WPF will instead call the `SetValue` method directly.

See MSDN [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) for an explanation why the setter is not called.

You would have to register a [PropertyChangedCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) with property metadata.

Comment: What a pity.  But I guess this answers the question.

Answer (score 6):

You should use a property changed handler in your dependency property directly. This way you ensure that it gets called when set in XAML:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(ucMyControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsSelectedChanged));

private static void OnIsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Implement change logic
}
```

Comment: I did that, but OnIsSelectedChanged still doesn't get called.

Comment: @Nickolodeon, you have to register the PropertyChangedCallback via the `PropertyMetadata` argument in [Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502.aspx).

Comment: @jjrdk, it's not only binding, the getter and setter are never called if the property is accessed in XAML.

Comment: @Nickolodeon Clemens is right. Unfortunately the full code sample is hidden off the right end of the code box.

Comment: Dan Puzey, wat exactly is gazumped?

Comment: That's ok that it's hidden, because I rewrote Register as public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(ucTopicItem), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsSelectedChanged));