# C# trigger method on setter of a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, dependency-properties

I am trying to trigger a method every time the property `Minutes` is changed, however it never happens. I am not setting the property through `XAML`, it is being set by a bidding.

```
public static DependencyProperty MinutesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Minutes", typeof(string), typeof(TimelineControl));

public string Minutes
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(MinutesProperty); }
    set { 
        SetValue(MinutesProperty, value);
        my_method();
    }
}

public void my_method()
{
    Console.WriteLine("foo bar");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DependencyProperty not triggered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212583/dependencyproperty-not-triggered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are setting the property through XAML, then your setter won't be called. To properly handle property changes, you should add a callback to the property's metadata when registering:

```
public static DependencyProperty MinutesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Minutes", typeof(string), typeof(TimelineControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(OnMinutesChanged));

private static void OnMinutesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle change here

    // For example, to call the my_method() method on the object:
    TimelineControl tc = (TimelineControl)d;
    tc.my_method();
}
```

Comment: I am setting the property through a bidding, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I've used such code many times and it should work no matter how the property is set. Perhaps you could post your XAML and your code?

Comment: One more info, if I call `dgTimeline.Items.Refresh()` after using `addTime` the Handle works.