# Set value of DependencyProperty directly

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

Ok so I have a test control that derives from Panel. I added new dependency property to it.

```
public class TestPanel : Panel
{
    public static DependencyProperty TestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Test",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(TestPanel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            0.0,
            null));

    public double Test
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)this.GetValue(TestProperty);

        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(TestProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I then defined it in xaml `<controls:TestPanel Test="50" />`

But now I wonder, why the setter of Test is not called? Shouldn't it pass value(50)? I get default value (0.0) during arrange pass.

Or is it only valid using the binding instead?

Comment: The WPF calls SetValue directly. So your setter will not be executed. But the Test value should be 50 after control initialization. Do you read this value anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, I had mismatch in dependecy properties, duplicate also point me to extended information, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XAML processor sets the value of the dependency property using the `SetValue` method:

[Setters not run on Dependency Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225373/setters-not-run-on-dependency-properties)

If you want to do something whenever the property is being set to a new value, you should register a callback:

```
public static DependencyProperty TestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"Test",
typeof(double),
typeof(TestPanel),
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
   0.0,
   OnPropertyChanged));

private static object OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Who downvoted this? this describes exactly what is wrong and how to mediate it

Comment: Not mine downvote, but there are plenty of duplicates, is the answer really needed? E.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9212583/1997232) is another one.