# Depedency Property Not Updated

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

Dependency property of my `UserControl` not trigger.My property inside usercontrol named `"MultiColumnComboBox"`=>

```
public readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSourceValue", typeof(List<EmployeeModel>), typeof(MultiColumnComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(new List<EmployeeModel>(),TargetPropertyChanged));
        public List<EmployeeModel> ItemSourceValue
        {
            get
            {
                return (List<EmployeeModel>)GetValue(ItemSourceValueProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ItemSourceValueProperty, value);
            }
        }   

private static void TargetPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

my xaml=>

```
<r:MultiColumnComboBox ItemSourceValue="{Binding EmployeeList}"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Margin="2"/>
```

I already check this link=>[Link 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/972f8e2a-c91f-4399-9573-c368ae74d23f/trigger-on-custom-dependency-property-not-firing?forum=wpf) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212583/dependencyproperty-not-triggered) but this is not work for me.

Comment: As a note, you must not use `new List<EmployeeModel>()` as default value for the dependency property. All instances of your control would operate on the same default collection object. That said, a Binding like `{Binding EmployeeList}` requires that there is an object with a public EmployeeList property in the DataContext of the control. The DataContext should be inherited from one of the parent elements, e.g. the MainWindow.

Comment: Yep,I am sure EmployeeList property is already exist in DataContext because I was used this property on another place of xaml and all are work fine.

Comment: I am facing this error till 1 day and not get solution yet :(

Comment: The problem is that your TargetPropertyChanged callback method is not called?

Comment: Yep.TargetPropertyChanged not called.

Comment: I put breakpoint at the start of `TargetPropertyChanged` Method and Setter of ItemSourceValue but they are never fire.

Comment: Note that the ItemSourceValue setter is bypassed when the property is set by a Binding. WPF directly calls SetValue instead.

Comment: Yep most of solution is say just adding `PropertyChanged` Method to Dependency Property.I followed all possible way to fix this error.Please let me known any other possible way you known.

Comment: Note also that `public readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceValueProperty` should be `public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceValueProperty`. However, provided that your EmployeeList view model property fires a PropertyChanged event, your code should work.