# Dialog should come to front on button click

Tags: wpf, prism

I am using Prism 5. To show dialog, I am using InteractionRequest. IsModel Property is set to False, so when I click on the main window (from where Dialogs is raised), Dialogs went in background. Now what I am trying to implement is that when I click button again, dialog should come to front again.

Here is my custom PopupWindowActionclass:

```
public class CustomDialogWindow : PopupWindowAction
{
    private Window window;

    protected override Window GetWindow(INotification notification) {
        window = base.GetWindow(notification);
        return window;
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty SetFocusProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("SetFocus", typeof(bool), 
                       typeof(CustomDialogWindow), null);

    public bool SetFocus {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(SetFocusProperty); }
        set {
            if (value) {
                if (window != null) {
                    window.Activate();
                    window.Focus();
                }
            }
            SetValue(SetFocusProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my XMAL side configuration:

```
  <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ContainerMoveSummaryRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
        <popout:CustomDialogWindow  x:Name="ContentSummaryGridAction"
                                                     IsModal="False" SetFocus="{Binding SetFocusOnContainerMoveSummary,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <popout:CustomDialogWindow.WindowContent>
                <dialogs:ContainerMoveSummaryDialog />
            </popout:CustomDialogWindow.WindowContent>
        </popout:CustomDialogWindow>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

The problem is even though binding is two way, On changing  `SetFocusOnContainerMoveSummary` , `SetFocus` is not getting change.

Please let me know any solution for this.

Comment: You can try to call a Focus method for the dialog, that will bring it to the front.

Comment: How ? Where to put the binding ?

Comment: Duplicate of [DependencyProperty not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212583/dependencyproperty-not-triggered/9212653#9212653)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is even though binding is two way, on changing `SetFocusOnContainerMoveSummary`, `SetFocus` is not getting called

This is expected behavior, the the framework circumvents the helper property and uses the dependency property directly.

You need to set a callback on the dependency property and go from there:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SetFocusProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SetFocus), 
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(CustomDialogWindow), 
        new PropertyMetaData( default(bool), OnSetFocusChanged);

private static void OnSetFocusChanged( DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs )
{
    // get the window from dependencyObject (= the CustomDialogWindow instance) and call SetFocus
}
```